# System.exit(1) java, equivalent in VB

Tags: java, vb6

Can anybody help in finding out what is the equivalent `System.exit(1)` Java, equivalent in VB6.

Comment: I only did a quick search, and this is for .Net, so it might not help, but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Environment.Exit(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, as you're talking VB6, not VB.NET, I think the best you can do is ...

```
Private Declare Sub ExitProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal uExitCode As Long)
```

And then when you want to exit, use, for example ...

```
' Exit with ErrorLevel set to 9
ExitProcess 9
```

Note, however, many dire warnings about ending a VB6 program in such an "untidy" way. See, for example, the thread at http://www.codenewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/topic10328.aspx